# azure chatbot SDK4 - live(human) agent chat REST API integration not working issue

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot

I stuck with azure chat-bot framework SDK4 integration with live agent(human) chat through REST API using Node.js.

1. I have an REST API, which needs to execute in the certain interval for getting information about human agent chat and status, and i need to send to user as an chat message.
2. One more REST API, which will send chat message again again to live agent from user.

I am trying to implement this in azure chat-bot SDK V4 waterfall method getting failed.

```
async liveAgentMsg(step) {
var msgObjMessages = await getLiveAgentMessages(); // API call
if (msgObjMessages.length > 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < msgObjMessages.length; i++) {
        var msgtype = msgObjMessages[i].type;
        if ('ChatRequestSuccess' == msgtype) {
            await step.context.sendActivity("Chat request success.");
        } else if ('ChatEstablished' == msgtype) {
            return await step.prompt('textPrompt', 'Live agent chat established.');
        } else if ('ChatMessage' == msgtype) {
            await step.context.sendActivity(msgObjMessages [i].message.text);
        } else if ('ChatEnded' == msgtype) {
            await step.context.sendActivity(msgtype);
            return await step.endDialog();
        } else {
            await step.context.sendActivity(msgtype);
        }
    }
    return await step.replaceDialog(SAME_DIALOG_ID);
} }    


async chatMsg(step) {
if (step.result) {
    var chatObj = await sendChatMessage(step.result);  // API Call
    if ("success" == chatObj) {
        return await step.replaceDialog(SAME_DIALOG_ID);
    } else {
        await step.context.sendActivity(chatObj);
    }
} 
return await step.endDialog(); }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your use of "returns" seems unusual. Why do you use return on some awaits and not on others? Also, you may want to look at this repo (https://github.com/tompaana/liveperson-bot-adapter) as it demonstrates transferring a conversation between a bot and a human. It may lend some insights into how you can structure your code better.

Comment: While implementing above scenario, I am facing one more issue with Direct line client, user chat messages status always shows "can't send, retry" even though messages are received at live agent side.

Comment: What channel are you using this over? You mention direct line - is this a custom channel, web chat, or something else?