# azure chat bot[SDK4] messages status shows 'can't send, retry', while on live(human) agent chat on Direct line channel

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am facing issue with azure chat-bot framework SDK4 integration with live agent(human) chat through REST API using Node.js.

- I have an REST API, which needs to execute in the certain interval
  for getting information about human agent chat and status, and i need
  to send to user as an chat message.
- One more REST API, which will send chat message again again to live agent from user.

I am trying to implement this in azure chat-bot SDK V4 waterfall method getting messages status shows 'can't send, retry', even though it received from live agent side.

Code already in stack overflow:
[azure chatbot SDK4 - live(human) agent chat REST API integration not working issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240098/azure-chatbot-sdk4-livehuman-agent-chat-rest-api-integration-not-working-iss)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go --> [echo bot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/02.a.echobot) this sample will explain listen for the incoming requests to bot.

Comment: Please explain better in your SI answer, rather than linking off to sites that might one day become deleted. If the page is deleted, we have no idea what your answer really was. Thanks,